# write a value to specific row and column using shell

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am very new to shell scripting, Task in my hand are divided into 2 shell scripts.

I want to do Pipelining of two shell scripts(which should run from a different directory rather than where the scripts are written) and which is presently working well.

First shell script contains:

1. Combining around 90 .lvm files stored inside a folder.
2. Crops each `.lvm` file, removes header and crops till the end of data.

**Now I need to print a value in the 18th column once each file have been  iterated to distinguish the end of file (here I am trying to write 500)**

```
#!/bin/sh
clear
for file in "$1/"*.lvm; do
    a=$(awk '/X_Value/{ print NR; exit }' "$file")
    b=$(awk 'END {print NR}' "$file")
    awk '{OFS= "\t"} {NR==$b $18,"500"}' "$file"
    #specified row is $b and column number is 18
    sed "s|\$a|${b}|" "$file"
done
```

Second shell script contains:

1. Reading specific columns from a first shell script.

Which is:

```
#!/bin/sh
clear
while read line; do
   sleep 1
   awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $1, $2, $3, $8, $18}'
done
```

---

**Output now:**

```
file1  196287,265000    3,902977    -39,226354  0,873427  
file1  196287,266000    3,890747    -51,032699  0,519405
file1  196287,267000    3,900080    -51,472975  -0,446108
....
....
....
file2 196287,268000 3,904586    -50,627182  -0,092086
file2 196287,269000 3,870793    -30,687314  1,195265
file2 196287,270000 3,897505    -30,073244  0,744692
....
....
```

---

**Desired Output:**

```
file1  196287,265000    3,902977    -39,226354  0,873427     0
file1  196287,266000    3,890747    -51,032699  0,519405     0
file1  196287,267000    3,900080    -51,472975  -0,446108    500
...
...
...
file2 196287,268000 3,904586    -50,627182  -0,092086  0
file2 196287,269000 3,870793    -30,687314  1,195265   0
file2 196287,270000 3,897505    -30,073244  0,744692   500
...
...
```

Comment: Could you please add few samples of your sample files in your post and more sample about your output too in your post.

Comment: use [printf](https://linux.die.net/man/1/printf) to format into fixed width columns consistently. Field formatting options are just like [C's printf](https://linux.die.net/man/1/printf), so `printf "%-25s%15s\n" $a $b` should left-justify $a in a 25 character wide field and right-justify $b in a 15-wide field.

Comment: If speed isn't an issue you could call another for loop to go through and append a final column per file ?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 are you asking me for .lvm file samples ?

Comment: @PaulHodges i understood your idea to print values but still how can i append values at end of each file, and also i think printf cant iterate between files,please correct me if i am wrong. and can you please show me an example with for loop. Thanks

Comment: @MikeQ That was an good advice, but for loop uses different files and due to mismatch in files between both for loop i am getting different solution than what i require

Comment: @jovel  your issue is simple unless I am missing something., I still fail to see why you couldn’t write the data for file 1 to file1tmp update file1tmp with your new column and then merge it into the master list of results ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not like awk. I do not use awk. Mock me if you must.
If bash can't handle something, I rewrite it in perl. =o)

That said - here's a clumsy all-bash version.
Many improvements to be made, but work keeps interrupting my fun, lol

```
nl="
"
for f in "$1/"*.lvm
do typeset out=''
   while read a b c d e
   do out="$out$( printf "%-25s%14s%14s%14s%14s%14s" $f $a $b $c $d $e )$nl"
   done <<< "$(cut -f 1,2,3,8,18 -d '   ' $f )"
   stack="$stack$nl$(printf "${out% *} 500$nl")"
done
echo "$stack"|grep -v '^$'
```